# Don't Allow User To Log Back In After Logging Out Of Drupal Site

Tags: webforms, forms, database, users

This might be a simple fix, but I cannot figure out how to do it or find a module that accomplishes this. I simply need to dis-allow a user to log back into a site after they have logged out. They need to be allowed one login only. After they log out, they are locked out.

Another thing that would accomplish my goal would be to hide ALL webforms once user has submitted ONE of the webforms. Upon submission, they are not allowed to submit any of the other forms.

So, either logging them out without ability to log back in, or hiding all webforms after ONE has been submitted. Either will accomplish my goal.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please ask one question per question, not two.

Comment: Hey Billy, 2 interesting questions, too bad 'this" is closed. How about MOVINg the question in your 2nd paragraph to a NEW question, and then asking for "this one" to be reopened (by flagging it like so). After you do, I'd be happy to provide an answer to both questions ... (send me a comment around here so I'm aware you did, ok?).

Answer (score 2):

You can use workflow rules to accomplish this. Create a new rule to react on "User has logged out" , then add an action to "Block user".

Comment: Note that you want to install the rules module for this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I can point you in right direction to get you started.

For reference [Drupal user api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/7)

1. Create role 'One time login'
2. User this module [node privacy by role](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_privacy_byrole) to give access to webforms only user who belongs to role 'One time login'
3. Write custom module which,

   3.1 Create custom table to store user one time login flag status

   3.2 Use hook_user_login() to see if your user has logged in before reading one time log in status flag and access to webform according to [node privacy by role](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_privacy_byrole)

   3.3 If above condition fails force logout.